# Curl to php or json

Tags: php, json, curl

i need help i've been trying to run this

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic dXNlckBjb21wYW55LmNvbTp0ZXN0" https://security.voluum.com/login
```

but quite stuck, also is it possible to create this in php or in json? i need data to create something. also i tried replacing dXNlckBjb21wYW55LmNvbTp0ZXN0 with my own 64bit username:pass but still not working can someone explain this i really dont know what to do

Comment: You could read documentation on CURL, read the PHP manual on CURL, search for other topics on StackOverflow to see if other uses also encountered this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case data for login is: `user@company.com:test`. And you can use `curl` in ssh like follows:

```
curl -u user@company.com:test https://security.voluum.com/login
```

**PHP**

You can also execute this in PHP as follows:

```
$user='user@company.com';
$pass='test';
$url='https://security.voluum.com/login';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "Status code: $status_code \n";
print_r($result);
```

---

**More informations**

**Base64**

`dXNlckBjb21wYW55LmNvbTp0ZXN0` == `user@company.com:test` you can decode/encode it by yourself [here](https://www.base64decode.org/)

**Curl**

More about `-u` you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737031/curlss-option-u). And curl manual is available [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)

**PHP**

[PHP:Curl Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)