# Using URLSeason to connect to github

Tags: ios, swift, rest

I'm working on `RestAPI` just to learn how to work with it.

For the testing phase, first I made a login page to get username and password, and trie to connect `github` with it. I am in early stage of my code, but since it is my first experience, I am faced with this problem.

here is my model (just for logging) and it's not completed yet:

```
struct LogginReguest {
    var username: String
    var password: String

mutating func gettingAceess() {
    let loginString = "\(self.username):\(self.password)"
    let resurceUrl = "curl -u \(loginString) https://api.github.com"
    guard let loggingUrl = URL(string: resurceUrl) else {fatalError()}

    let logging = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: loggingUrl)
    logging.resume()
}
```

}

I use this page for using github API

https://developer.github.com/v3/

The first problem is, in this line::

```
    guard let loggingUrl = URL(string: resurceUrl) else {fatalError()}
```

The app crashed and it showed `fatalError`

It is not recognizing it as the URL. Could you help me on that? And can you tell me how I can read the login error problem from the github server? It would be a great help.

Comment: the content of `resurceUrl` is not a valid url, it's a unix command with arguments.

Comment: How I can fix it for github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert your curl in url

```
let username = "username"
let password = "password"
let resourceUrl = "https://\(username):\(password)@api.github.com"
guard let loggingUrl = URL(string: resourceUrl) else {fatalError()}
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42833854/3493517

Comment: I really appreciate for your help